# Override or bypass accessors in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, setter, getter-setter

I'm trying to replicate the ivar/setter access of Objective-C in Swift.
Here is a simple exemple of setter versus ivar use in Objective-C :

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end


@implementation Person

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    // Let's assume that this is an expensive operation.
    // I want to perform it only when necessary.
    _name = name.capitalizedString;
}

- (void)someMutatingMethod1
{
    Person *otherPerson = nil; // Get a person
    NSString *newName = otherPerson.name;

    // At this point, I know that newName is in the corect format because it comes from a Person object.
    // I don't need the expensive setter work, so I bypass it with direct ivar access.
    _name = newName;
}

- (void)someMutatingMethod2
{
    NSString *userInputName = @"john";

    // It's user input, I need the setter to perform it's work.
    self.name = userInputName;
}

@end
```

The closest way to replicate this class in Swift is this :

```
class Person {
    private var _name: String?
    var name: String? {
        get {
            return _name
        }
        set (newName) {
            _name = newName?.capitalizedString
        }
    }

    func someMutatingMethod1() {
        let otherPerson:Person? = nil;
        _name = otherPerson?.name;
    }

    func someMutatingMethod2() {
        let userInputName = "john";
        self.name = userInputName;
    }

}
```

But it's a pain because accessors are not automatically synthesized and I have to write them manually. And it's confusing because I can now use `_name`, `name`, `self._name` and `self.name`.

Now, most answers on Stack Overflow suggest that I write this :

```
class Person2 {
    var name: String? {
        didSet {
            self.name = self.name?.capitalizedString
        }
    }
}
```

But I think this is confusing and unclear about my intentions. I'm not trying to perform some *cascade mutation* **after** setting the name property, I'm trying to mutate the value passed to the setter **before** setting the value. And again, I want to be able to privately bypass this setter which is not possible with this approach.

How comes that I can't just write this :

```
class Person3 {
    var name: String? {
        set (newName) {
            name = newName?.capitalizedString
        }
    }
}
// This one actually makes the compiler crash on Xcode 7.2
```

or this :

```
class Person4 {
    var name: String?

    override func setName(newName) {
        name = newName?.capitalizedString
    }
}
```

or even this :

```
class Person5 {
    var name: String? {
        willSet(newName) {
            return newName?.capitalizedString
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is there is just no way of having the same construct that Objective-C has ?

Comment: Your first implementation using `_name` is exactly correct, and also happens to exactly match how the ObjC works. There's nothing wrong with it, at the cost of maybe two lines of "unnecessary" code. Working around that just makes things more complicated, as you note.

Comment: Well it looks the same yes but doesn't work the same because both `name` and `_name` are properties in this case (with default accessors synthesized for `_name`). But maybe the separation between ivars and properties doesn't exist in Swift ?

Comment: I still think that I'm going to go with this implementation everywhere for clarity but I'm surprised that there isn't a built in way of doing this without writing so much code like there is with Objective-C...

Comment: you're correct that there isn't the strong ivar/property duplication like there is in ObjC. In most cases that's a benefit. If you're doing this a lot (setting properties to things that aren't their actual value), you should ask whether  you're doing something else wrong. In general, after foo.x=y, foo.x should return y. If it doesn't, it isn't really a "property" and you should probably write an explicit updateX() method to make that clear (and making the setter private) rather than overriding the setter.

Comment: That said, ObjC has exactly this kind of duplication all the time when working with CoreData or locking. You often have to maintain "primitive" accessors. (See primitiveValueForKey:)

Comment: I agree with you first comment, this was more of a theoretical question than anything else, I've never written an entire iOS app in Swift. I still hope something will be added for this in future versions of Swift though. And you're right about Core Data, but I'm just starting with Swift and if it turns out to have the same level of complexity than Core Data, then one will have to explain to me why it's supposed to be easier than Objective-C...

Comment: It's much safer than Objective C. I have no idea why people would consider it easier. (Though in fairness, it is more regular than ObjC. Far fewer differences between objects and primitive types. Still, Swift is a quite complicated language.)

Comment: Totally agree with you. I guess it depends which language (if any) you learned before Swift. I knew C pretty well, so Objective-C felt easy, but I guess Swift being closer to scripting languages might be easier for some people.